# Not recognizing widget as parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

Why my widget parameter is not being recognized in the same stateful widget instance? When I pass is as a parameter in a parent widget?

[Code example of parameter failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cKBw.png)

[Parameter passing in parent widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXepO.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Next time, please post your code, not an image.

Comment: You can paste images straight into questions. Having people follow links to new tabs creates a lot of work in comparing different images. But, really you should just paste this as a code block in the question,, like others are saying.  Also, it's not so clear what parameter you are talking about. It's probably body_page. If that's the case, it looks like John answered this correctly.

Comment: Hi @SpiRail I was not very careful after I posted it in order to edit it and correct this issue. I'd like to thank you both for taking the time to read my poorly made post and solve it. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your widget is stateful, you need to access your parameter using `widget`. in this case, it should be:

```html
body: widget.body_page,
```

Comment: Hi @John, first I'd like to apologize for the way this post was made. Was my first post and I thought images will display directly and not as links. After I posted it I tried to edit it to paste the code directly but I could find a damn edit option and simply gave up assuming no one would take me seriously. Of course this answer was absolutely on point and resolved my issue.